# confused about the preg_match expression

Tags: php

preg_match uses an expression of casses like

```
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $content, $matches);
```

so I am confused about creating the patterns how is this developed /[(.*?)]/ as I am trying to create a shortcode and want if any one places the short code any where in the page I can get the shortcode from there and clean up and know what shortcode is placed like [shortcode app='slider' id='2'] i need slider and 2 from the shortcode so I can show the slider and replaced the slider with the shortcode

Comment: I am not clear about your problem. Do you need anything to fix in the pattern?

Comment: I am confused how to create the patterns

Comment: In think you can check the edit made in your question. (Already fixed the problem in your pattern. ) :)

Comment: I don't know how it is edited but I just want to know how these patterns are created

Comment: It was edited by one of the SO community.

Comment: @UsmanKhan Look at https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the explanation

`\[` - matches character with "[". "\" is used to escape it because we have special meaning for it in regular expression.

`(` - `)` will capture the part inside to be used as a back reference while we replace

`.*` - any character can be present here except line breaks and it can be 0 or more times.

`?` - makes the previous part optional (which is not necessary here, cause using `*` already takes care of it, which means 0 or more times.)

`\]` - matches one character "]"

Learn more on regular expressions from here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/